# How to iterate over a tHashOutput in a tJava component in Talend

Tags: java, talend

Is it possible in a tJava to get a reference to a tHashOutput component?

I am need to iterate over the data I have accumulated in a tHashOutput, so I can create a DataSet object related to the JFreeChart library.

I was hoping it was just a Map object and I could grab it from the globalMap, but that isn't working.

And I certainly can't simply get a reference using the component name:

```
System.out.println(tHashOutput_1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to link your `tHashOutput` with a `tHashInput`, then you can access the data.

In the first picture you can see I used a fixed flow to input values into the `tHashOutput`.

[image]

Then I link it to a `tHashInput` which sends its output to a `tJavaRow`.  In my example I simply stick the values into the GlobalMap object.  This is a simple example and involves one row, but you should be able to use morph it to your own situation now that you have the basic technique.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to be able to iterate it manually via a tJava somehow, but I ended up doing this in the end.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in a `tHashOutput`, are accessible only by `tHashInput` component. Once you read the data by a `tHashInput` component, you can use a `tJavaRow` component to iterate over rows but not with `tJava`, because any component suffixed by the word `row` is executed for each row.